# не пойму вывод команды ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash

мне нужно найти все файлы в папке `*.conf` в директории без подпапок, я нашел командной

```sh
find . -name '*.conf' -maxdepth 1
```

Но ради интереса добавил в команду -ls и вывод одной строки смутил:

`./yum -> dnf/dnf.conf` - что это значит?

Comment: символическая ссылка.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что файл присутствует в папке, просто он "зеркалит" файл на который ссылается ? или это просто ярлык как в винде ?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: спасибо, уже нашел ответ, на другом ресурсе